# Remote profiling ASP.net Applications?

Tags: asp.net, .net, profiling

Using Visual Studio, I can profile an ASP.net Application using the Performance Wizard (specifically Instrumentation is what I want).

I need to diagnose why a production server is slow, but I don't want to install Visual Studio on it. Also, It's not enough to use something like ASP.net MVC Mini Profiler because I don't control all the code and thus can't get the granularity that I need.

Can I use the Visual Studio Remote Profiler somehow? Windbg? Anything that's not as intrusive as Visual Studio and can be cleanly uninstalled after.

Comment: It could be useful adding different performance logs which could be enabled/disabled via config. Byperformance logs I mean code block wrapped by stopwatch calls with measurement of code block execution time.

Comment: @sll I don't control the code I want to profile, the pieces of code I do control don't offer enough granularity :( I would need something that really looks inside the Virtual Machine, like a Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetbrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/index.html) can do remote profiling of asp.net applications, it has a free trial, it is commercial though.